# How do you loop FBX animations

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, procedural, looping

I have a 39 frame walking cycle from Mixamo and I want to keep looping it through but not where he keeps going back into his first position. I am very new to character animation in Blender so I really can't find how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a video explaining how: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgPDe2GoiRY

What you want to do is open the graph editor, and select the keyframes that you wish to loop over (over their respective time period), press Shift + E, and select "Make Cyclic (F-modifier)".

Comment: Well that got me closer. The remaining issue is that the guy shoots back to where he first started on frame 1 of the cycle; and also when I added the cycle modifier, it set it to a huge timeline (something like 10,000 [in the positive and negative direction]. Any ideas?

Comment: From your description it appears that you are trying to loop a (I'm going to guess) a walk cycle with root motion applied.
This means that as the character does the walk animation, he probably also moves forward in the scene, when in reality you probably want him walking in place.
If this is your issue, then I'm afraid that the only solution is to find the bone with the forward motion, and delete its keyframes. 
Though you'll probably have to adjust a whole bunch of other stuff on the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to graph editor and find the forward motion graph line(only one that goes up super high) and do a linear extrapolation on it. us make cyclic (F-modifier for the rest)